# Spring boot and Spring Actuator - disable security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using spring-boot 1.3.1 and spring-boot-actuator in my application. I am using the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as the parent in `pom.xml`.

To disable the security, I added 2 entries in my `application.yml`.

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

It is still not disabling the basic security. I am seeing the default password in log file when I start the application in my local tomcat.

Answer (score 3):

Basic security is **disabled** but Spring Boot  configures the authentication manager with the default user/pass even after setting `security.basic.enabled` to `false`. *But basic security is disabled.* You can reconfigure the `authenticationManager` in order to override this behavior, like following:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("me").password("secret").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If Spring Security is present, you would need to add a custom security configuration that allows unauthenticated access to the endpoints. Something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//....

@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/actuator/**");
        super.configure(web);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stop spring boot to log default password by setting username/password in your application.yml -

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  user:
    name: user
    password: ****
```